# Sort objects while inserting (if same exists then add data)

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a little problem and don't know how to handle it.

I have struct called Person:

```
struct Person
{
    string name;
    vector <string> address;
};
```

I also have vector of these structs.

```
vector<Person> people;
```

I need to:
Sort **Person**'s by name in people vector (ascending), but if person with same name exists in vector then add him another address (address.push_back(address);). 
I need put new Person object(or add address) in right place **when inserting** (not to sort vector after insert).

Comment: Why not use e.g. [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead? With the name as the key and the `Person` as the data?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a homework then i think you are expected to implement some algorithm instead of using complicated data structure which will do sorting 'automagically'.

Here is the clue: if element we are searching for does not exist in the vector, then binary search algorithm will stop right at the position where the new element belongs.

Java implementation of binarySearch does exactly this - it returns *insertion point* - a special value which can be converted into position in the array where new element should be inserted still maintaining the propery of 'sorted'.

In C++ you would have to implement it yourself. Something like this: [Binary search to find the range in which the number lies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935635/binary-search-to-find-the-range-in-which-the-number-lies) .

May be try reimplementing Java behaviour with std::lower_bound().

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a sorted data structure like std::map (binary search tree). This would keep your data sorted and insertions/queries would be of time complexity O(log n).

See [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) for supported operations.

Vector may not be efficient since you want to make insertions and reallocations can get very expensive depending on the size of your data.