# Has C# something like C++ std::equal_range?

Tags: c#, c++

I have been searching and did not really find an answer. To be honest, I think that there is really a little of information for usage of this function in the internet. The reference itself isn't clear enough for me to find an equivalent in C#.

I have to port a C++ class to C#. The old C++ class uses this function at one point and I replaced it with the usage of LinQ using Where(), which is provided by enumerable objects:

```
std::equal_range(it_begin, it_end, value, comparer)
//changes to
list.Where(/*some comparison using the same comparison logic and the value like C++ version*/)
```

Unfortunatelly I don't get the same ranges like in the original code. So I'm wondering if I replaced the C++-Method with the correct equivalent or if I have some logic-errors in my comparison code.

So what is the correct equivalent of std::equal_range in C#? Is my solution the right one or is the equivalent something totally different?

Edit:

Thanks for the hint to say something to the C++ function.

First [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) is the documentation

After all as far as I understand it, I returns a range of a list which contains all values which are like the given value. A User can provide a comparer where I'm not completely sure for what this is used:
 - to compare the values in the list with the given value?
 - to compare for the sorted result?

Edit2:

The reason for my different results was located somewhere else. So considering the complexity criteria I've accepted Matthews answer. Allthough considering the result all 3 solutions (Matthews, Renés and mine) deliver the same result. So if performance doesn't matter and/or less code is wished, maybe one of the other solutions will be OK for you.

Comment: It would be helpful for the C# audience if you spent some time detailing what equal_range does.

Comment: [Documentation for equal_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) (in case OP doesnt edit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this with binary search.

This is essentially an identical implementation to equal_range(), and therefore has the same complexitity of ~O(Log2(N):

([Implementation of lower and upper bound stolen from here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10935920/106159))

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var values = new List<string>{"1", "2", "3", "5", "5", "5", "7", "8", "9"};

            test(values, "5");
            test(values, "-");
            test(values, "A");
            test(values, "4");
            test(values, "6");
        }

        public static void test<T>(IList<T> values, T target) where T: IComparable<T>
        {
            var range = EqualRange(values, target);
            Console.WriteLine($"Range for {target} is [{range.Item1}, {range.Item2})");
        }

        public static Tuple<int, int> EqualRange<T>(IList<T> values, T target) where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            int lowerBound = LowerBound(values, target, 0, values.Count);
            int upperBound = UpperBound(values, target, lowerBound, values.Count);

            return new Tuple<int, int>(lowerBound, upperBound);
        }

        public static int LowerBound<T>(IList<T> values, T target, int first, int last) where T: IComparable<T>
        {
            int left  = first;
            int right = last;

            while (left < right)
            {
                int mid = left + (right - left)/2;
                var middle = values[mid];

                if (middle.CompareTo(target) < 0)
                    left = mid + 1;
                else
                    right = mid;
            }

            return left;
        }

        public static int UpperBound<T>(IList<T> values, T target, int first, int last) where T : IComparable<T>
        {
            int left  = first;
            int right = last;

            while (left < right)
            {
                int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
                var middle = values[mid];

                if (middle.CompareTo(target) > 0)
                    right = mid;
                else
                    left = mid + 1;
            }

            return left;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this solution delivers the same results as my solution. I will investigate further what goes wrong or if reason for my problem is located somewhere else and will update my initial posting.

Comment: @Onsokumaru I'm pretty sure that this is the same as the C++ implementation. Can you post some sample code that shows your collection, the target value, your expected results and your actual results?

Comment: Just in this second as you posted the comment I was brainstorming how to "close" this question. Your Code does the same as Renés and mines. All three solutions deliver the same result. Finally I found out that my code contained a mistake at another place which is not related to the equal_range thing. I was thinking about making this as wiki-question since all 3 solutions seem to be a correct equivalent?

Comment: @Onsokumaru I think an important criteria for equal_range() is that it has O(Log2(N)) complexity. So although the results may be the same, mine is the only version that has the right complexity. You'd really notice the difference on a big collection!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand `std::equal_range`, this extension method should be an equivalent:

```
public static class CppExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> EqualRange<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T val, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        return source.EqualRange(val, comparer.Compare);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> EqualRange<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T val, Func<T, T, int> comp)
    {
        return source.SkipWhile(s => comp(s, val) < 0).TakeWhile(s => comp(s, val) == 0);
    }
}
```

Testprogram:

```
test[] list =
{
    new test {a = 1, text = "a"},
    new test {a = 2, text = "b"},
    new test {a = 3, text = "c"},
    new test {a = 3, text = "d"},
    new test {a = 4, text = "e"}
};

IEnumerable<test> result = list.EqualRange(new test {a = 3, text = string.Empty}, (t1, t2) => t1.a.CompareTo(t2.a));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result.Select(r => r.text)));
```

This outputs `c d`.

Comment: (if the complexity requirement is ignored)

Comment: @BenVoigt I admit that I did not care about complexity (which one definitly should do if this method is used very often or for big data). OP did not explicitly asked for it and I have no idea of `std::equal_range`'s complexity. I think my code is straight forward and smart people will surely find lots of performance improvements.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this solution delivers the same results as my solution. I will investigate further what goes wrong or if reason for my problem is located somewhere else and will update my initial posting.